# Append input box with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to add text into field with id #shouttext, but i need to trim value from onclick event which is just after (' and also delete ') symbols.

So if i have

```
<img src="images/smilies/at.png" alt="" title="" class="smilie smilie_9 smilie_pointer" onclick="MyBBEditor.insertText(':at:');">
```

I want to get

```
:at:
```

and add it to input with #shouttext id. Below is my code, which doesn't work - and i think its blocked by defined onclick value, which i was trying to remove.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.smilie').click(function()
{
   var s1,s1;
   s1=attr("onclick");
   s1=s1.replace('MyBBEditor.insertText(\'', '');
   s2=s1.replace('\')', '');
   $('.smilie').attr('onclick','').unbind('click')
   $('#shouttext').val($('#shouttext').val()+s2);
}) 
});
</script>
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Do you have control over the image tag?

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: just wondering if you can remove the click handler on the element itself.

Comment: @GamaPL so actually a user enters some text inside a textarea, than chooses a Smily and you want to insert `:at:` inside the textarea?

Answer (score 1):

you could try also:

```
var str = $(".smilie").attr("onclick").split("'")[1];
```

to get the `:at:` try it here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meougz1L/2/)
now you can use it here:

```
$('.smilie').unbind("click");
$('.smilie').click(function() {
    var str = $(".smilie").attr("onclick").split("'")[1];
    $('#shouttext').val($('#shouttext').val() + "" + str);
});
```

or how @eg_dac says, you can override the `click` event with `$.on()`

Answer (score 0):

instead of unbinding it in the click, you can do

```
$(".smilie").attr("onclick", ""); // clear the already declared attribute.

$(".smilie").on("click", function(){
    $('#shouttext').val($('#shouttext').val()+s2);
});
```

Example found here http://jsfiddle.net/meougz1L/

```
$("img").attr("onclick","");

$("img").on("click", function(){
    alert("click event overridden");
});
```

Comment: also, don't forget to delegate the event if needed.